# sticky nav reveals content behind it while scrolling slowly

Tags: css, nav, sticky

I made a fiddle that demonstrates this behavior:
https://jsfiddle.net/fatmh6oc/

My desired outcome is a nav bar at the top of the page that sticks there even while scrolling. I assumed that using `position: sticky; top: 0;` would achieve this. It mostly does, but there is a terrible-looking visual effect here when you scroll down slowly. Even though I am using a CSS reset in my project to make sure default margins are set to 0, I can still see a sliver of other content **above** the navbar, even despite the `top: 0`!

Am I implementing this wrong, or is there possibly a better way that doesn't come with this side-effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try `position: fixed` and `z-index:2`

Comment: That solved it! I still wonder why ```position: sticky``` reveals a sliver above, but this is a good solution.

Comment: I think this article can help 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position